# How do I send an SOH character over telnet from an sh script?

Tags: sh, special-characters, telnet

I'm running a fairly simple sh script that automates a few telnet commands, but I've run into an issue.

One command requires an SOH character (normally sent using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>) followed by the command name, then enter. This is a snippet of that, but it doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/sh
(
echo open 12.34.56.78
sleep 2
echo -e "\u001""commandname"
echo -e "\n"
sleep 3
echo "quit"
) | telnet
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I send that SOH character via the script?

Comment: `echo -e` is not supported by POSIX shell. Either change your shebang to `#!/bin/bash`, or use `printf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `printf`.

```
{
  printf "open 12.34.56.78\n"
  sleep 2
  printf '\001commandname\n\n'
  sleep 3
  printf 'quit\n'
} | telnet
```

Comment: The commandname in my script is a number (300), making the input supposed to be [SOH]300. Given that, is the syntax correct on that line in your example? `printf '\1300\n\n`  ?

Comment: Ah, nevermind. I forgot about `%b` to escape the backslash. So the correct syntax in my case would be `\1%b300\n\n`

Comment: I probably shouldn't have simplified it as I did. The octal number can be 1-3 digits, so zero-padding it to avoid ambiguity is a good idea in any circumstance, but essential here.